# AWS Auto Scaling Group SNS Notifications to trigger at certain number of scaled instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-auto-scaling

I currently have an Activity Notification set for our Auto Scaling Groups for 'launch' type. It fires based on any amount of launches. Is there a way to restrict the Notification to send only when we are over a certain amount of scaled instances? For example I have max 15 instances to scale to, I'd like to get Notifications only when we're over 10 scaled instances.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to "restrict" the notification.

However, you could create an **Amazon CloudWatch alarm** on the `GroupTotalInstances` metric. When that metric exceeds a desired value, it can trigger a notification.

See: [Monitoring CloudWatch metrics for your Auto Scaling groups and instances - Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-instance-monitoring.html)